# Changing ADUC Account expiration date via command saves wrong date

Tags: batch-file, active-directory

I am trying to make a simple batch file to change a user's ADUC expiration to a specified date.

Using the below command the date always appears in ADUC as one day prior to what I set:

```
net user myname /expires:09/17/13 /domain
```

In ADUC, the date will be: 09/16/2013. No matter what, the date that appears in ADUC is one day before the day I set.

The documentation I found for this indicates

> Note that the account expires at the beginning of the specified date.

So does this mean, If i wanted the account to be expired today, I would send the command for today and ADUC would interpret that as yesterday?

Thanks in advance, I just want to get this right.

Answer (score 0):

As a wild guess, since you're UTC-savvy - is the date UTC date, so 130917T0000Z=130916T1900 local?